# Compute new column based on values in current and following rows with dplyr in R

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe, dplyr

I have a big dataset (10+ Mil x 30 vars) and i am trying to compute some new variables based on complicated interactions of current ones. For clarity i am including only the important variables in the question. I have the following code in `R` but i am interested in other views and opinions. I am using the `dplyr`  package to compute new columns based on current/following row values of 3 other columns. (more explanation below code)

I am wondering if there is a way to make this faster and more efficient, or maybe completely rewrite it...

```
# the main function-data is a dataframe, windowSize and ratio are ints
computeNewColumn <- function(data,windowSize,ratio){

     #helper function used in the second mutate down...
     # all args are ints, i return a boolean out 
     windowAhead <- function(timeTo,window,reduction){

     # subset the original dataframe-only observations with values of
     # TimeToGo between timeTo-1 and window (basically the following X rows 
     # from the current one)
     subframe <- data[(timeTo-1 >= data$TimeToGo & data$TimeToGo >= window), ]
     isthere <- any(subframe$Price < reduction)
     return(isthere)
     }

  # I group by value of ID first and order by TimeToGo...  
  data %<>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(desc(TimeToGo)) %>%

  # ...create two new columns from simple interactions of existing ones...
  mutate(Window = ifelse(TimeToGo > windowSize, TimeToGo - windowSize, 0),
         Reduction = floor(Price - (ratio * Price))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%

  #...now comes the more complex stuff- I want to compute a third column 
  # depending on the next (TimeToGo - Window) number of values of Price
  mutate(Advice = ifelse(windowAhead(TimeToGo,Window,Reduction),1,0) ) 

return(data)
}
```

We have a dataset with the following columns: ID,Price, TimeToGo.

We first group by values of ID and compute two new columns based on current row values (Window from TimeToGo and Reduction from Price). Next thing we would like to do is compute a new third column based on

1.current value of Reduction

2.the next (Window - TimeToGo) amount of values of Price in the dataframe.

I am wondering if there is a simple way to reference upcoming values of a column from within `mutate()`? I am ideally looking for a sliding window function on one column, where the limits of the sliding window are set from two other current column values. My solution for now just uses a custom function which subsets on the original dataframe manually, does a comparison and returns back a value to the `mutate()` call. Any help and ideas would be much appreciated!

p.s. heres a sample of data... please let  me know if you would need any more info. Thanks!

```
> a
           ID TimeToGo Price
1 AQSAFOTO30A       96    19
2 AQSAFOTO20A       95    19
3 AQSAFOTO30A       94    17
4 AQSAFOTO20A       93    18
5 AQSAFOTO25A       92    19
6 AQSAFOTO30A       91    17
```

Comment: For anyone interested - I came across the [caTools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caTools/caTools.pdf) package which has a nice rolling min/max function with adaptive (varying) window size. This solves one half of my problem, it still remains to implement the window on one vector(TimeToGo) while the computation takes the according values from another (Price)...