# Compute new column based on values in current and following rows with data.table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, subset

I have already posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570320/compute-new-column-based-on-values-in-current-and-following-rows-with-dplyr-in-r) question, unfortunately without any success. In the meantime I discovered the `data.table` package and tried to compensate speed for memory by using the nice 'update by reference' style it offers. I noticed `data.table` has a pretty lively and helpful community so I was wondering if someone here can maybe help me further.

The link with the other question I posed goes more into detail, here I would simply like to know the way to reference "upcoming" values in the `i`- expression i.e.  I have a datatable with a key - I want to compute new columns in the `j`-expression, based on subsets of current and following row values for another column in the `i`-expression, all done grouped by Key.
Something like this:

```
data[TimeToGo %in% seq(TimeToGo-1,TimeToGo-7), 
     MinPrice := min(Price),
     by = key(data)]
```

Which would basically go through each value of `TimeToGo` (like `TimeToGo[i]`), subset on the datatable with values of `TimeToGo` in `(TimeToGo[i]-1, TimeToGo[i]-7)` and pull out the `min(Price)` from this subset as the new column entry `MinPrice` (at index `i`). 
The result of such a try gives back the following error :

```
Error in seq.default(data$TimeToGo - 1, data$TimeToGo - 7  : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

I've tried using `by = .EACHI` and error persists. On the other hand, a solution which uses `for`-loops was very very slow, so I thought there must be a better way to do this.

I would greatly appreciate any help, opinion, direction, reference for further reading...

Thanks in advance

d

Comment: At first glance this looks like an application for `shift`, are you using the development version of the package?

Comment: Upon a brief look at the earlier question,  `foverlaps` might be what you need.

Comment: Hey @Michael and @Khashaa, thanks for the comments! Well, I had a look at your proposals and the problem with the `shift` function is that it assumes uniform gaps in between obs, which is unfortunately not true my case - a span of 7 days can have between 7 and 1 observation. That's what it makes using any kind of 'window' function so difficult, because one has to apply the windowing on TimeToGo, check for which days actually observations exist in that window and then get the min Price out.

Comment: And as for the `foverlaps` function - I still didn't have a proper look at the documentation and examples, but it might be that, with some transformation on the data, it could achieve what I want. As I understood, it basically joins two tables which share intervals in the same fields. One might be smaller than the other - which comes handy in the case that I have less obs than days in some interval. I will give it a try and let you know how it went. Thanks again for the comments!

Comment: I do believe that this should be possible just by using the standard syntax like `data[ J(seq(TimeToGo-1, TimeToGo-7)), 
                MinPrice := min(Price), 
                by=ID]` ...tried out couple of variations (using J() or even a function that takes the current TimeToGo as an input and returns all the Time's in that window) but I still get the same error. I don't quite understand why, as  such subsetting in the `i`- expression is quite standard, as well as the `j` and `by` expressions...

Comment: @3.14159 `seq` is not a vectorized function

Answer (score 2):

Use `foverlaps`:

```
dt = data.table(time = c(1:4, 10:14), b = 1:9)
dt[, end := time] # necessary for the foverlaps atm
#   time b end
#1:    1 1   1
#2:    2 2   2
#3:    3 3   3
#4:    4 4   4
#5:   10 5  10
#6:   11 6  11
#7:   12 7  12
#8:   13 8  13
#9:   14 9  14

intervals = dt[, .(start = time - 1, end = time + 7, idx = .I)]
setkey(intervals, start, end)

foverlaps(dt, intervals, by.x = c('time', 'end'))[, max(b), by = idx]
#   idx V1
#1:   1  4
#2:   2  4
#3:   3  5
#4:   4  6
#5:   5  9
#6:   6  9
#7:   7  9
#8:   8  9
#9:   9  9
```